# Target a div within series of divs that has same class name

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have this kind of structure:

```
<form>
 <div class="name"></div>
 <div class="name"></div>
 <div class="name"></div>
 <div class="name"></div>
</form>
```

I'm having trouble targeting each div. I should be able to target the first and second div. Any inputs on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I'm not getting your problem. Can you please give some more detail

Comment: You can use jQuery's .eq() method, e.g. $('form').eq(1), or you can use any of the standard CSS selectors, e.g. $('form div:first-child'), $('form div:nth-child(n)') etc. Which is best really depends what your requirements are.

Comment: `$('div.name')[0]`, `$('div.name')[1]`, etc...

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask]. There are numerous ways to target specific elements depending on what you are trying to accomplish bu your question is not specific enough

Comment: Sorry about that but what I'm asking is how could a target either the first or second div where they're all of same classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.eq(i)` will parse a given collection and return the item indexed by *i* (zero based, so 0 is the first item in the collection).

```js
$("form").find("div").eq(1).addClass("red");
$("form").find("div").eq(2).addClass("blue");
```

```css
div { background-color: yellow; padding: 5px; }
div.red { background-color: red; }
div.blue { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <div class="name">first div</div>
 <div class="name">second div</div>
 <div class="name">third div</div>
 <div class="name">fourth div</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery then you can use `$.each()` to target them without an event:

```
$('.name').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (index == 0) {
      // do something for first .name element using $this
    } else if (index == 1) {
      // do something for second .name element using $this
    }

});
```

If you want to target them with a `.click()` event then use:

```
// First .name element
$('.name:first-child').click(function(){
   // Do something
});

 // Second .name element
$('.name:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
   // Do something
});
```